# Ringtone and vibration not working on Nexus 5 (Android 5.0.1)

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, nexus-5, ringtone, vibration

Ringtones and vibration stop working on my Nexus 5 (using Android 5.0.1) when receiving a call. There were working before, but I don't know why the ringtone and vibration just stop.

I tried different things: restarting the phone, updating the software, changing the setting ringtones, turning off-on these settings for both ringtones and vibration, etc.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Sorry. I just found the problem. It seems pretty obvious but I coudnt found any help in the web.... The point is that when you increase the volumen of the ringtone (with the left key of the phone) 3 different options shows up. In my case te option "priority" was on. It should be "all" !

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! On SE sites, it's perfectly fine to [answer your own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question) – but answers should be posted as answers, not as part of the question-post or a comment to it. Mind moving it to a separate answer? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and it was so annoying, because I missed all the important call due to this error or setting. I didn't change this setting and only Nexus phone know how it changed this setting.

Please follow the steps below and it will start ringing.

1. Press <kbd>Volume Up</kbd> key on the the phone.
2. Select the option "Indefinitely"
3. Select the Settings icon (the wheel icon)
4. Under "Priority interruptions" section, enable Calls.

Enjoy, no more missing calls

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Please follow the below steps:

1. Press on volume key (up or down)
2. On the Gray menu select None and Indefinitely
3. Exit the menu by clicking on the main screen
4. Press on volume key again
5. Select All.

It should work now.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but opened the back panel and replaced it back again. I think it's because the vibrator is on the back panel. Maybe a loose connection could also cause this.

Before removing the back, remember to switch off your mobile.